# Deterministic nature of .NET Dictionary<TKey,TValue> enumeration

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, deterministic

I understand that the ordering of entries within a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` is not defined. However, is it deterministic?

That is, if I add the same elements in the same order and enumerate through the Dictionary, will I *always* get the elements in the *same* order, on *every* run, on *every* machine?

It *seems* that's the way it is, but could I rely on it?

Comment: No, like in SQL. In most cases true but ...

Comment: Dictionary uses hash code of an elements, I don't think that order can be deterministic. In .NET Core `GetHashCode()` can return a different values for the same objects in different runs

Comment: There's no guarantee; even `GetHashCode()` can well return *different values* (on different work stations) on the same argument(s)

Comment: @Dimitry - Surely a hash must be deterministic - same input, same output? Otherwise, you would be able to add multiple entries in a Dictionary against the same key.

Comment: @Pavel - is the hash is deterministic, then the order would also be deterministic, surely? For me the order is not significant - merely that it is repeatable.

Comment: @Neil Moss: if you compute `GetHashCode` on *different workstations* but for the same input, the results may be different

Comment: @Dmitry - thanks - I think that is the clincher then. Do you have a reference/example of this behaviour?

Comment: It is at the very least untrue if `TKey` is `string` and [randomized string hashing](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/userandomizedstringhashalgorithm-element) is enabled, aside from being undefined in general (meaning that it is technically legal for the implementation to return a brand new order on every call, even on an unchanged dictionary, although practically it will of course not do this).

Comment: @NeilMoss I've updated my comment above, in .NET Core `GetHashCode()` can return a different values for the same objects in different runs

Comment: not only that, you can override gethashcode, who knows what wonderful things implimenters are doing

Answer (score 1):

Taken from documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1

*For purposes of enumeration, each item in the dictionary is treated as a KeyValuePair structure representing a value and its key. The order in which the items are returned is undefined.*

Comment: Thanks. I understand that - whilst it is not defined what ordering results, is the ordering consistent? Or, given MS say "is undefined" should I assume that ordering is _not_ consistent?

Comment: @NeilMoss: "Undefined" is borrowed from C semantics ("undefined behavior") and means "you can't assume anything and we reserve the right to invalidate your assumptions at any time". It would literally be permissible for the implementation to explicitly randomize the results on every call. All it promises is that iterating will get you all the elements, but nothing else. (For a more practical and less mean scenario, imagine that the implementation was changed in the next version to exploit parallelism, with the order becoming non-deterministic due to timing changes.)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks all - it looks like the answer is a flat "NO".

The [MSDN docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.gethashcode?view=netframework-4.8) for String.GetHashCode declares:

> The hash code itself is not guaranteed to be stable. Hash codes for
>   identical strings can differ across .NET implementations, across .NET
>   versions, and across .NET platforms (such as 32-bit and 64-bit) for a
>   single version of .NET. In some cases, they can even differ by
>   application domain. This implies that two subsequent runs of the same
>   program may return different hash codes.

If hash codes are variant, then elements may end up in different buckets and so enumerate in a different order.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a hybrid of a list and a dictionary so that you get deterministic order

```cs
public class DeterministicThing<TKey, TValue> :
    IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>
    where TKey : notnull
{
    private readonly ImmutableList<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> kvpList;
    private readonly ImmutableDictionary<TKey, TValue> kvpDictionary;

    public DeterministicThing(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> kvps)
    {
        kvpList = kvps.ToImmutableList();
        kvpDictionary = kvps.ToImmutableDictionary(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value);
    }

    public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> GetEnumerator() => kvpList.GetEnumerator();
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => kvpList.GetEnumerator();
    public TValue this[TKey key] => kvpDictionary[key];

    public int Count => kvpList.Count;
}
```